# Global scope ok with 2 variables but 3rd with identical treatment produces error

Tags: python, global-variables

I'm working on learning tkinter but running into a problem with variable scope. In the code below 3 variables are declared global: bid, max*score, and flg. None are declared global inside the function. Two work just fine but the third does not.*

*When the 1st entry loses focus and val_1 (the callback routine) is entered, the values bid and maxscore have the values initially assigned but the variable flg produces the error: "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'flg' referenced before assignment". Yet it has been assigned exactly as the other two variables have. All 3 are treated equally. The print statement was added to confirm the values on entry. When the print statement does not contain "flg" I find the correct values for bid and max_*scores and "flg" errors out on the if statement. Put "flg" in the print statement and it blows up there. I must be violating the scope somehow but darned if I can see it.

Can anyone see what's happening ?

The Code:

```
import os
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from tkinter import messagebox

global bid
global max_score
global flg

max_score = 25
bid = 20
flg = False

root = Tk()

f1_txt = StringVar()
f2_txt = StringVar()


def setup():
    field_1.config(textvariable=f1_txt, validate='focusout', validatecommand=val_1)
    field_2.config(textvariable=f2_txt, validate='focusout', validatecommand=val_2)
    return

def val_1():

    print (bid, max_score, flg)
    if flg :
        return True
    else:
        flg = True

    s1 = int(f1_txt.get())
    s2 = max_score - s1
    
    if s1 < bid:
        messagebox.showinfo("UH-OH","Looks like someone went up !!")
        s1 = 0-bid
        
    f1_txt.set(str(s1))
    f2_txt.set(str(s2))
        
    flg = False
    return True

def val_2():
    pass

    
root.geometry('300x300+20+20')
field_1 = ttk.Entry(root,width = 5)
field_1.grid(row = 0, column = 1, pady = 30, padx = 15)

field_2 = ttk.Entry(root,width = 5)
field_2.grid(row = 0, column = 2, pady = 30, padx = 15)

field_1.focus_set()
setup()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please add the full traceback message so we can quickly see which line is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Variables assigned in a function or method are assumed to be local. You assign `flg = True` in the function so its a local variable. The others are merely referenced, so they are assumed to be global. The `global` keyword is used *inside a function* to change this rule for that one function only. Saying `global bid` at module level is meaningless - its a puzzle why this doesn't raise an error. It is only useful within a function to change a variable's assumed scope.